# GDB using STM32 on Mbed: "virtual memory exhausted"

Tags: debugging, gdb, stm32, mbed

I am trying to debug an application using GDB on the Mbed Windows 10 operation system. However, after a few steps, GDB always fails with the error:

> /mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-10-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-10-pipeline-338_20211018_1634516203/src/gdb/gdb/utils.c:671: internal-error: virtual memory exhausted: can't allocate 4064 bytes.
>
> A problem internal to GDB has been detected, further debugging may prove unreliable.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues/619
it looks like bug in arm gdb v 10.3
I saw somewhere it should be fixed in 11 something but I am unable to find that page again.

Answer (score 0):

This error occured recently in a fairly big project out of nothing. Using different gdb releases from 9 to 11 did not make a difference. After removing all breakpoints the error disappeared. It occured again when setting breakpoints on certain class functions.